# Tableau - Informix connection

Tags: sql, database-connection, informix, business-intelligence

I am trying to call a stored procedure through Tableau for an ODBC Informix server.

In QlikSense if I run the same query I am able to retrieve the data (because of this I think it's a syntax issue)

The Custom SQL query I am testing is:

```
call standard_sp('2023-10-24 22:00:00','2023-10-25 21:59:59','0')
```

The error I got is:

> Error Code: 2F0F5E42
> [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.

Comment: Without seeing the SQL that is causing that error, there is not much we can do to help.  That is, regrettably, an extremely anodyne error; it simply means that the SQL present was inscrutable.  But without knowing what was going on inside `standard_sp()`, there's not much hep we can offer.  There are debugging techniques that monitor what's sent on the wire between your client and server, but that generally requires special setup in various ways which my or may not b easy to achieve in the Tableau environment.  Your best hope is probably that code for `standard_sp()` is available.

Comment: Hi, the standard_sp() is doing standard transformation and returning multiple integer number (not a table)

Answer (score 0):

Tableau data source can not direct execute stored procedure, make table for result the procedure. Then tableau can read the table result as data source.